# Pulling data out of quotes?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for a regex that can pull out quoted sections in a string, both single and double quotes.

IE:

```
"This is 'an example', \"of an input string\""
```

Matches:

- an example
- of an input string

I wrote up this:

```
 [\"|'][A-Za-z0-9\\W]+[\"|']
```

It works but does anyone see any flaws with it?

EDIT: The main issue I see is that it can't handle nested quotes.

Comment: The regular expression you give doesn't seem to match your example string at all. What about spaces inside quotes?

Comment: I think you mean [\"'], because [\"|'] will be matching the | (pipe) as well. You don't need the pipe to express an "or" in square brackets.

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks> Specifically these answers: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks#171499>
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks#172996>

Comment: Doesn't that allow a single quote at the start and a double quote at the end, or vice versa, as well as the same quote at start and end.

Answer (score 3):

How does it handle single quotes inside of double quotes (or vice versa)?

```
"This is 'an example', \"of 'quotes within quotes'\""
```

should match

- an example

  of 'quotes within quotes'

Use a backreference if you need to support this.

```
(\"|')[A-Za-z0-9\\W]+?\1
```

EDIT:  Fixed to use a reluctant quantifier.

Comment: This does not work for strings like this one: "foo foo \"match\" foo \"match\" foo", where it returns "\"match\" foo \"match\"" as the only match.

Comment: That's because \W is the non-word character class, not the whitespace class, as I thought.  My memory's not what it used to be.

Comment: No. :-) Is is because the "+" greedily matches to the end of the string, before backtracking occurs and the last applicable quote is given to back-reference "\1".

Comment: And for that matter, with the "\s" you now have in place it is not going to match punctuation, or accented characters, or greek characters, etc...

Comment: Okay, that's my fault.  I misunderstood what was to be matched.  I thought it was matching alphanumerics and spaces.  So changing to a reluctant quantifier is the ticket here.

Answer (score 1):

Like that?

```
"([\"'])(.*?)\1"
```

Your desired match would be in sub group 2, and the kind of quote in group one.

The flaw in your regex is 1) the greedy "+" and 2) [A-Za-z0-9] is not really matching an awful lot. Many characters are not in that range.

Comment: I think you mean "\1", not "$1".

Comment: Corrected that already. Sometimes I confuse regex dialects a bit, "$1" is the back reference of the VBScript regex implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It works but doesn't match other characters in quotes (e.g., non-alphanumeric, like binary or foreign language chars). How about this:

```
[\"']([^\"']*)[\"']
```

My C# regex is a little rusty so go easy on me if that's not exactly right :)

Comment: That doesn't return any matches at all.

Comment: I changed it to use the parens instead of the [], since I think it was thinking the period as a literal period instead of wildcard. I tested it out in Ruby with your example string and it seems to match them fine.

Comment: But the greedy start runs over any quotes there are and you will get the longest match, but not the right match.

Comment: In that case, the first match also contains the rest of the string in my test string

Comment: ah, i missed that one. this regex seems to work better: just capture everything that's not a quote

Answer (score 0):

```
@"(\"|')(.*?)\1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might already have one of these, but, in case not, here's a free, open source tool I use all the time to test my regular expressions.  I typically have the general idea of what the expression should look like, but need to fiddle around with some of the particulars.

http://renschler.net/RegexBuilder/