# Regex - how to extract text from between quotes and exclude quotes

Tags: regex

I need help with regex. I need to create a rule that would preserve everything between quotes and exclude quotes. For example:
I want this...

```
STRING_ID#0="Stringtext";
```

...turned into just...

```
Stringtext
```

Thanks!

Comment: More info needed: Can there be more than one quoted string in your input? Can there be escaped quotes? Which regex engine are you using?

Answer (score 4):

The way to do this is with capturing groups.  However, different languages handle capturing groups a little differently.  Here's an example in Javascript:

```
var str = 'STRING_ID#0="Stringtext"';
var myRegexp = /"([^"]*)"/g;
var arr = [];

//Iterate through results of regex search
do {
    var match = myRegexp.exec(str);
    if (match != null)
    {
        //Each call to exec returns the next match as an array where index 1 
        //is the captured group if it exists and index 0 is the text matched
        arr.push(match[1] ? match[1] : match[0]);
    }
} while (match != null);

document.write(arr.toString());
```

The output is

```
Stringtext
```

Comment: You can do this shorter:        let result = []; let regex = /myRegex/g;
        let match = regex.exec(data);
        while(match) {
          result.push(match[1]);
          match = regex.exec(data);
        }

Comment: Best answer because it does not produce errors in Safari either, since this regex does not use lookahead or lookbehind.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
function extractAllText(str) {
       const re = /"(.*?)"/g;
        const result = [];
        let current;
        while ((current = re.exec(str))) {
            result.push(current.pop());
        }
        return result.length > 0 ? result : [str];
    }

const str =`STRING_ID#0="Stringtext"`
console.log('extractAllText',extractAllText(str));


document.body.innerHTML = 'extractAllText = '+extractAllText(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"
```

I recommend reading about REGEXes
[here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)

Comment: That doesn't remove the quotes from around the string.

Comment: Ouch, don't know how I forgot about it.
But Tim Pietzcker is right, user should specify the REGEX engine

Answer (score 0):

```
"(.+)"$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/IVBA8Lluu4hcNV8S)

This was asked in 2011.....

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(?<=(["']\b))(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?(?=\1)
```

[DEMO](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/770c06fc3a36).