# Java - Regex - Capture group between " "

Tags: java, regex

Do you know what is wrong here?

```
    Pattern pathsPatter = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+)\"");
    Matcher pathsMatcher = pathsPatter.matcher(commandAndParameters[1]);
```

I want to capture the group between " ". For example, if the string is

```
    mv "C:\Users\" "D:\"
```

the matcher should capture:

```
    C:\Users\
    D:\
```

Comment: What output do you get now?

Comment: Nothing. It doesn't capture anything.

Comment: it is already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks

Comment: It works for me http://ideone.com/vsx1fQ

Answer (score 1):

Try out this pattern :

```
    String data = "mv \"C:\\Users\\\" \"D:\\\"";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"(.+?)\"");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
    System.out.println("Started");
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here:

```
Pattern pathsPattern = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+)\"");
Matcher pathsMatcher = pathsPattern.matcher("mv \"C:\\Users\\\" \"D:\\\"");
pathsMatcher.find();
System.out.println("found " + pathsMatcher.group(1)); // prints: found C:\Users\
pathsMatcher.find();
System.out.println("found " + pathsMatcher.group(1)); // prints: found D:\
```