# RegEx: Grabbing value between quotation marks from string

Tags: java, regex, string, matching, capturing-group

This is related to: [RegEx: Grabbing values between quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks).

If there is a String like this:

```
HYPERLINK "hyperlink_funda.docx" \l "Sales"
```

The regex given on the link

```
(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1
```

is giving me

```
[" HYPERLINK ", " \l ", " "]
```

What regex will return values enclosed in quotation mark (specifically between the `\"` marks) ?

```
["hyperlink_funda.docx", "Sales"]
```

Using Java, `String.split(String regex)` way.

Comment: Thats not working. Giving - " HYPERLINK "hyperlink_funda.docx" \l "Sales" " in entirety.

Comment: I'm assuring you, it is working. [Take a look here.](http://regex101.com/r/gJ0nE3/1)

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: That's working in general but I'm using Java and using String.split(regex) way. Specifically, String[] parts = " HYPERLINK \"hyperlink_funda.docx\" \\l \"Sales\" ".split("\\\\\".*?\\\\\"");.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to use that with `.split()` method. Instead use a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) with capturing groups:

```
{
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\"'])((?:(?=(\\\\?))\\3.)*?)\\1");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(" HYPERLINK \"hyperlink_funda.docx\" \\l \"Sales\" ");

    while (matcher.find())
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

> Output:
>
> hyperlink_funda.docx
>   Sales

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/fD7fK6/2), and here is an [online code demo](http://ideone.com/IhvfVU).

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misunderstanding the nature of the `String.split` method. Its job is to find a way of splitting a string by matching the features of the separator, not by matching features of the strings you want returned.

Instead you should use a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and a [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

```
String txt = " HYPERLINK \"hyperlink_funda.docx\" \\l \"Sales\" ";

String re = "\"([^\"]*)\"";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re);
Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
    String match = m.group(1);
    matches.add(match);
}
System.out.println(matches);
```