# RegEx: Grabbing text between quotation marks for selective switch

Tags: regex

This is related to: [RegEx: Grabbing values between quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks).

If there is a String like this:

```
HYPERLINK "hyperlink_funda.docx" \l "FunHere" \o "text" \t "_parent"
```

What regex could return the value enclosed in quotation mark **only for switch \l**?

```
FunHere
```

Comment: try this `\\l\s*"\K[^"]*`

Comment: People should suggest the reason if they down vote. I don't see any thing incorrect in getting the regex for the scenario in question.

Comment: i'm not the downvoter , downvote is because of there are large number of questions like this on SO. A simple searching will give you the exact regex. And also you need to show your attempts.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I could not find any with selective selection. Please add link if you're seeing any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there's no escaped `"` or lines in `// comments` that should be accounted for:

```
\\l\s*"([^"]*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/jrFi9fkFJg-M4tky) Your match will be in group 1.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex will capture the required words in the 1st capture group:

> \\l\s*"(\w+)"