# Regular expression, selects a portion of text inside other

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I am a bit clueless about the next task.  I wish to select a text between " that its inside a tag but not outside of the tag,i.e. a selection inside another selection.

I have the next tag: <|  and |> and i want to select a text only if its between the " and between the tags.

<| blah blah blah "**should be selected**" not selected "***select it too***" |>  "not selected too"

I think something about

```
(\<\|)(\").*?(\")(\|\>)
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: @nicael did you even read the question? OP wants to select values between quotation marks only if its inside tags `<|` `|>`

Comment: Yes, its not a duplicated, i don't want to select any text inside " ", i want to select a text that is inside " " and <| |>   and its JS and C#

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary it doesn't matter, solution easily adjustable. You just imagine that `<|` and `|>` are another quotes and improve the regex.

Comment: @nicael Do you care to elaborate the easy solution?

Comment: @nicael i dont think its easy adjustable. if its easy for you it doesnt mean its easy for everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the job in a single regex:

[`(?<=<\|[^>]*)"[^"]*"`](http://goo.gl/s3SwNh)

In addition to a comment of nicael: It might be possible that the input string is not tagged correctly. This will help:

[`(?<=<\|((?!\|>).)*)"[^"]*"`](http://goo.gl/DqgQRC)

If you need to use it with JavaScript:

[`(?=("[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)"[^"]*"(?=((?!<\|).)*\|>)`](http://regexr.com/3cf39)

Comment: Looks great, but why doesnt it work [there](http://regexr.com/3cet3)? On mobile, cant get the error to be displayed.

Comment: Found a problem in your regex: [this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%3c%5c%7c%5b%5e%3e%5d*)%22%5b%5e%22%5d*%22&i=%3c%7c+blah+blah+blah+%22should+be+selected%22+not+selected+%22select+it+too%22+%3e+%22not+selected+too%22+%3c%7c+%22test%22+%7c%3e+%22wrong+match%22+) doesn't match correctly. I replaced first |> with > , this should cause "not selected too" to match, though it doesn't.

Comment: @nicael I added a regex that solves the second problem. My regex will work with .Net regex. Your fist sample shows that look behind assertions are not allowed in JavaScript. Sorry. What's that? There is a regex that doesn't support look behind? I try to find a solution that works with look ahead assertions.

Comment: @nicael Will [`(?=("[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)"[^"]*"(?=((?!<\|).)*\|>)`](http://regexr.com/3cf39) be a possible solution? It looks strange if you remove the `|` of the first closing token but maybe it's okay.

Comment: This one seems to be perfect!

Comment: @nicael The regex in my edited answer solves the problem you posted in the second comment.

Answer (score 6):

I've got it to match correctly using two regexes.

```js
var input = '<|a "b"|>c "d"ef<|"g"h "i"|>"j"k l';
var output=input.match(/<\|(.*?)\|>/g)
   .map(function(x){return x.match(/"(.*?)"/g)})
alert(output)
```

As you can see, correctly matches "b","g","i".

The principle:

1. find all the matches of text between `<|` and `|>`
2. for every match from the first step, find matches of text between two quotes.

(used the regex from the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/171483) from the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks) question)

Comment: The greedy `*` quantifiers will eat the first pair of `<|`, `|>` if several are present: https://regex101.com/r/wI4lF2/1

Comment: @Jan hm, this does seem to be the problem. Tested using OP's example.

Comment: @Jan edited: as answer mentioned javascript, used it :)

Answer (score 3):

[I can't think of a regular expression to match what you want in one shot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34381697/regular-expression-selects-a-portion-of-text-inside-other#comment56506977_34382182) but I don't see the reason not to do it with two regexps:

```js
var SAMPLE_STRING = '<| blah blah blah "should be selected" not selected "select it too" |> "not selected too" <| "select it" do not select this |> "don\'t select this one too"';

var matchAll = function matchAll(regexp, str) {
  var lastIndex = regexp.lastIndex;
  regexp.lastIndex = 0;
  var result = [];
  var match;
  while ((match = regexp.exec(str)) !== null) {
    result.push(match[0]);
  }
  regexp.lastIndex = lastIndex; // so this method won't have any side effects on the passed regexp object
  return result;
};

var withinTagsRegexp = /<\|([^|]|\|[^>])+\|>/g;
var withinQuotesRegexp = /"[^"]+"/g;

var withinTagsAndQuotes = [].concat.apply([], // flattens the following
    matchAll(withinTagsRegexp, SAMPLE_STRING).map(
    matchAll.bind(undefined, withinQuotesRegexp)));

// show the result

var resultTag = document.getElementById('result');

withinTagsAndQuotes.forEach(function(entry) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = entry;
  resultTag.appendChild(p);
});
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it with look-behinds and look-aheads:

```
(?<=\<\|.)(\"[^"]*\")(?=.\|\>)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Here's a [live demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/O5VbAST6jV_7SHxi).

Comment: @fardjad oh, you're right. The answer by nicael fails at your example, too. Do you have better suggestions?

Comment: Yes, but not with a single regex, I'll post my solution in a minute.

Comment: That's odd... I would expect this to match only the `"test"` part of fardjad's example (instead of matching too often), because you only allow one character between the `|` and opening `"`, and only one character between the closing `"` and `|`. http://pythex.org/ seems to agree... is that Debuggex bug, a Pythex bug, or something else entirely?