# How to extract the strings in double quotes for localization

Tags: objective-c, regex, terminal, grep

I'm trying to extract the strings for `localization`. There are so many files where some of the strings are tagged as `NSLocalizedStrings`, and some of them are not.

I'm able to grab the `NSLocalizedStrings` using `ibtool` and `genstrings`, but I'm unable to extract the plain strings without `NSLocalizedString`.

I'm not good at regex, but I came up with this   `"[^(]@\""` 
and with the help of grep:

```
grep -i -r -I "[^(]@\"" * > out.txt
```

It worked, and all the strings were actually grabbed into a txt file, but the problem is ,

if in my code there is a line:

```
  ..... initWithTitle:@"New Sketch".....
```

I only expect the grep to grab the `@"New Sketch"` part, but it grabs the whole line.

So in the `out.txt` file, I see `initWithTitle:@"New Sketch"`, along with some unwanted lines.

How can I write the regex to grab only the strings in double quotes ?

I tried the grep command with the regex mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks), but it gave me syntax error .

For ex, I tried:

```
 grep -i -r -I (["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1 * > out.txt
```

and it gave me

```
 -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: I think it's talking about the first parenthesis.  `grep -i -r -I (` I think it needs a quoted string.

Comment: why can't you use the export/import tool in xcode?

Comment: I always want to use it, but the translation guys who work for our company doesnt want us to use it.Hence the hard way!@EugeneZhenyaGordin

Comment: If you plan to localize your app, you need to use `NSLocalizedString` for every string in your code that you need to localize. Update your code base once and do it right. It will save you a ton of effort over time.

Comment: I agree @rmaddy, I will do that if I can't find any easier way.

Comment: That is the easier way in the long term. Your code may be full of strings that shouldn't be localized. In my own code, I flag such lines with a `// NO_I18N` comment. Everything else uses `NSLocalizedString`. Then you can use the proper tools to extract the strings and get the files that need to be translated. No need to scan some home grown list of strings and manually removing the lines that shouldn't be localized. Think how this will work over time as you update and add code.

Comment: That's the problem @rmaddy, I was given the task to do localization where the other developer team who developed this whole SDK didn't take care of localization. They didn't even left the flags or some sort of indication for the not localized strings. Now I have to manually go through each line and do find and replace.Hence I posted the question looking for the easier way to grab those strings in double quotes and send them to trnaslation, and in the meanwhile I could update each statemtn with NSLocalizedString.Again, I totally agree with your statement. I will update the question as I move on

Comment: atleast this out.txt file will guide me where the strings are :P

Answer (score 0):

In xcode, open your project. Go to Editor->Export For Localization...It will create the folder of files. Everything that was marked for localization will be extracted there. No need to parse it yourself. It will be in the XML format.

If you wanna go hard way, you can then parse those files the way you're trying to do it now ?! It will also have Storyboard strings there too, btw.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when we do this, only the strings tagged as NSLocalizedStrings will be exported but not the plain strings.

Comment: storyboard localization is done, it is just these class files that are left.

Comment: that's correct...I've done localizations like that. It's easier to go and add NSLocalizedString to all the strings that have not being marked first, otherwise you'll have this pain all the time. Especially adding/changing strings.