# Regex to get terms between ""

Tags: regex

```
a:29:{i:0;s:2:"34";i:1;s:2:"35";i:2;s:2:"37";i:3;s:2:"36";i:4;s:2:"38";i:5;s:2:"41";i:6;s:2:"33";i:7;s:2:"17";i:8;s:2:"20";i:9;s:2:"18";i:10;s:2:"19";i:11;s:2:"22";i:12;s:2:"23";i:13;s:2:"16";i:14;s:2:"21";i:15;s:2:"43";i:16;s:2:"70";i:17;s:2:"91";i:18;s:2:"50";i:19;s:2:"48";i:20;s:2:"49";i:21;s:2:"53";i:22;s:2:"47";i:23;s:2:"46";i:24;s:2:"44";i:25;s:3:"106";i:26;s:3:"121";i:27;s:2:"95";i:28;s:2:"86";}
```

I need to get the values inside the `{}`, that are between `""`

Comment: R way https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-extract-a-string-between-2-characters-in-r-and-sas/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx: Grabbing values between quotation marks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far better would be to use `unserialize()` (if you're under `PHP`):

```
$str = 'a:29:{i:0;s:2:"34";i:1;s:2:"35";i:2;s:2:"37";i:3;s:2:"36";i:4;s:2:"38";i:5;s:2:"41";i:6;s:2:"33";i:7;s:2:"17";i:8;s:2:"20";i:9;s:2:"18";i:10;s:2:"19";i:11;s:2:"22";i:12;s:2:"23";i:13;s:2:"16";i:14;s:2:"21";i:15;s:2:"43";i:16;s:2:"70";i:17;s:2:"91";i:18;s:2:"50";i:19;s:2:"48";i:20;s:2:"49";i:21;s:2:"53";i:22;s:2:"47";i:23;s:2:"46";i:24;s:2:"44";i:25;s:3:"106";i:26;s:3:"121";i:27;s:2:"95";i:28;s:2:"86";}';
$your_var = unserialize($str);
print_r($your_var);
```

Afterwards, you'll have a beautiful array, see [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/GT7Opi)

---

To provide another, *less appropriate solution*:

```
\w+:"(\w+)"
```

See a demo for this one on [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/tN6zJ7/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can using this `"\w*"`.
[Here](http://rubular.com/r/kkzTkEaRU9) is the test.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a possible scenario, but you mention "inside the `{}`", so if unwanted quoted numbers can occur outside the braces, this should do it for you:

```
"(\d+)"(?=[^{]*})
```

It matches the number inside quotes, then using a positive look-ahead, makes sure a `}` follows before any `{`.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bF1vE3/1).