# Regex to get find string between double quotes

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for regex to return value between the double quotes in a given string.
I am using below java code

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");

Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
int findline = 0;

while (m.find()) {
System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

The above code work fine for normal text but not for below string

```
String originalString ="value = value.replaceAll(", ", ",").replaceAll(",", "\",\"").replaceAll("\\[","\""); ";
```

On javafile it will be like

```
String originalString = "value = value.replaceAll(\", \", \",\").replaceAll(\",\", \"\\\",\\\"\").replaceAll(\"\\\\[\",\"\\\"\"); ";
```

Now what i am looking for is if the data between double quote contain

```
\ or \" or \\
```

then ignore that rest everything it should return.

Rest all value between double quote contain escape char so ignore that content.

Comment: check this :[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks)

Comment: Can you provide the output for the given input strings using your current code?

Comment: Thanks for quick support. I tried it but not luck. It is not working with my text.

Comment: Sure with my current code I am getting out put like below , 
,
,
\

\\[
\

Answer (score 0):

you want to 'eat' exactly one character after the \ it is like this in perl

```
if( $line =~ /(?:(?:[\\]?+.)|.)*?"((([\\]?+.)|.)*?)"/ ){
    print $1;
}
```

if java you will need to protect each \ and "

```
Pattern.compile("(?:(?:[\\\\]?+.)|.)*?\"((([\\\\]?+.)|.)*?)\"");
```

if the java Pattern doesn't work try with JRegex.