# RegEx: Grabbing values between not escaped quotation marks

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind, nedit

This question is related to [RegEx: Grabbing values between quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks)

The RegEx from the best answer

```
(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1
```

tested with the

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/P3MMdnF7XbF1aplD)

also matches strings that start with an escaped double quote. I tried to extend the definition to work with a negativ lookbehind.

```
(["'](?<!\\))(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Ez69CRgfnXzevp5a)

but this does not change anything in the matched pattern.
Any suggestions on how to exclude escaped singe / double quotes as a starting pattern?

I want to use this as a highlighting pattern in nedit, which supports regex-lookbehind.

example for desired matching:

```html
<p>
  <span style="color: #ff0000">"str1"</span> notstr
  <span style="color: #ff0000">"str2"</span>
  \"notstr <span style="color: #ff0000">"str4"</span>
</p>
```

Comment: These kinds of input strings should never occur. The regex can look like `(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1`, but you will have to adjust it further.

Comment: thanks a lot, my rookie mistake regarding the lookobehind position i guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using negative [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for the backslash not preceded by another backslash, i.e.

```
(?<!(?<!\\)\\)["']
```

solves the problem:

```
((?<!(?<!\\)\\)["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?(?<!(?<!\\)\\)\1
```

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/R9J010/2)

You should be very careful about this approach, because generally regex is not a good tool for parsing inputs in markup syntax. You would be better off using a full-scale parser, and then optionally applying regex to parts that you get back from it.

Comment: No, it does not actually solve the problem because it will fail a valid match if a quote is preceded with an escaped backslash representing a literal backslash.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are right, I didn't think of escaping the escape character itself. Surprisingly to me, applying a negative look-behind inside a negative look-behind was allowed to patch for single occurrences of escaped backslashes. Of course now it will fail for escaped backslashes followed by non-escaped backslashes, but regex's inability to count puts a limit to how far this whole thing can be pushed.

Comment: You cannot  use lookbehinds here like that. You will fail another valid match. The only "valid" (to some extent) approach is the one I mentioned in the comment.

Comment: is it necessary to repeat the lookbehind for the last "\1" or does the backreference actually contain the lookbehind-behaviour? Either way in this special case it's not necessary because the middle part takes care of quotes preceded by a backslash after the starting quote