# Find php variables that are used inside single quotes incorrectly

Tags: php, regex

I want to run a regex search from inside PhpStorm (could be any file manager though, Double/Total Commander handles regex searches just as well) to match php variables that are inside single quotes and therefore string interpolation won't work on them e.g. `'$var'`.

The content of the files would be something like this:

```
$var = 'Hello world!';

echo 'Lorem ipsum $var dolor sit amet'; // Match this.
echo "Lorem ipsum 'dolor sit amet $var consectetur' adipiscing elit"; // But not this.
echo "Lorem ipsum 'dolor sit amet \$var consectetur' adipiscing elit"; // Or this.
```

I want the regex search to match the first statement, but not the second or third.

I've tried `'[\w ]+\$[\w]+[\w ]+'` but that doesn't work because it matches all statements regardless of the double quotes or escaped dollar sign. ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cNpzPD/4/)).

This is just a regular regex search that I want to run on my repo to find buggy code.

What regex could I use for this?

<sub>(I don't need to get any text in between quotes, just php variables in between single quotes that aren't escaped.)</sub>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx: Grabbing values between quotation marks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks)

Comment: I've absolutely no idea of what you need, very unclear.

Comment: Just add `(?![\w$ ']+")` at the end (assuming that `\w$ '` are the only character allowed in a string)?

Comment: Thanks @horcrux ! That works! Can you post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @David could you provide a working sample of horcrux's answer ?

Comment: Here @MostafaHussein [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cNpzPD/5/) `'[\w ]+\$[\w]+[\w ]+'(?![\w$ ']+")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is negative lookaround. In particular, negative lookahead, because in PHP you are not allowed to use no-fixed-length lookbehind:

```
'[\w ]+\$[\w]+[\w ]+'(?![\w$ ']*")
```

`(?![\w$ ']*")` means that the string that you want to match must not be followed by a `"`, with any number of character (the ones that you want to allow in a string) in the middle.

See also: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html