# Matching a result in c#

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have the following string

```
background-image: url(&#39;https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/files.domain.com/uploads/image/file/168726/carousel_IMG_6455.jpg&#39;)
```

and I just want to get the image URL.

My code is:

```
image = image.Replace(@"&#39;", "\"");
Match match = Regex.Match(image, @"'([^']*)");
```

**Match.Success** returns nothing, so I can not get the image URL.

Is there something missing? This used to work but not now.

Comment: You are replacing “&#39;” with a double-quote `"` and your regex is looking for a single-quote `'`.

Comment: I tested in regex hero and dotnet fiddle (https://dotnetfiddle.net/hH1eBE), and I think the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/171499/5758637 will work for you.

Comment: @DourHighArch Yes!! That was the problem. In some situation is enclosed with " and others with '

Comment: if any of the answers solves your problem, please accept the answer to close the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex of: `(\".*\")`

Will match the URL given the input string: 
background-image: url("https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/files.domain.com/uploads/image/file/168726/carousel_IMG_6455.jpg")

```
image = image.Replace(@"&#39;", "\"");
Match match = Regex.Match(image, "(\\\".*\\\")");
```

**Edit:**
If you are looking for something that will match pairs of single quotes or double quotes you could use:

```
(\".*\"|'.*')

Match match = Regex.Match(image, "(\\\".*\\\"|'.*')");
```

Answer (score 1):

The following pattern achieves your result, without the usage of `string.replace`.

```
var pattern = @"&#39;(?<url>.*)&#39;";
Match match = Regex.Match(image, pattern);
Console.WriteLine($"Math: {match.Groups["url"].Value}");
```

If you want the `"` surrounding the string, add this:

```
var result = $"\"{match.Groups["url"].Value}\""
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for a regex, just

- Split the string with `&#39;` substring
- Find the element starting with `http`
- Return the first found item.

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/uUvhtw):

```
var s = "background-image: url(&#39;https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/files.domain.com/uploads/image/file/168726/carousel_IMG_6455.jpg&#39;)";
var res = s.Split(new[] {"&#39;"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Where(v => v.StartsWith("http"))
    .FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(res);
// => https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/files.domain.com/uploads/image/file/168726/carousel_IMG_6455.jpg
```

If you need to use a regex, use the standard regex to match a string between two strings, `start(.*?)end` where `(.*?)` *captures* into Group 1 any 0 or more chars other than a newline, as few as possible as the `*?` quantifier is *lazy*:

```
var s = "background-image: url(&#39;https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/files.domain.com/uploads/image/file/168726/carousel_IMG_6455.jpg&#39;)";
var res = Regex.Match(s, @"&#39;(.*?)&#39;").Groups[1].Value ?? string.Empty;
Console.WriteLine(res);
// => https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/files.domain.com/uploads/image/file/168726/carousel_IMG_6455.jpg
```

See [another C# demo](http://ideone.com/RbnNpE)