# Get what is in string from one quotation mark to other

Tags: c#, string

I have a long string and I need to take part of it according to a certain condition. Let's say I have the following string:

```
string str = "fjashfdkj sdbf hbdf sfbjsh  hsdfj T=\"sadhj ad jh\" kdhad a P=\"sdkahda\"";
```

I want to take everything that is in `" "` after `T=` or `P=`. Is it possible to do that without knowing how many values are inside of quotation marks? As I figured I could find the location of `T=` in the string and check the next 12 values after, **if** I knew how many values there are.

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks

Comment: Btw: Are your slashes going the wrong way or is that on purpose? In C# we escape quotes by writing `\"` or `""` in verbatim strings.

Comment: thats a mistake on my part, meant to write \.

Fixed it, thank you for noticing