# How to extract all string inside the "" in a given string ? (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, arrays, string, extract

Given the string like this

```
This is a string - ["Testing", [["Test" , 0]] , [["TTest2",0,[23]]]
```

How can i extract all string in the double quote "" into an array like Testing, Test, TTest2 ?

Comment: If the whole thing is a string, then you need to do some complex string manipulation. but if it is a part of json, then you can format it into an array and work with that.

Comment: how can i do the string manipulation ?

Comment: many ways to do it. using regex is one of it. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to loop through your external array, and for each element check:

- If it's a string, add it to an array.
- If it's an array, then go into it and repeat the same process
- If it's any other type, move forward.

This can (should) be done recursively.

Comment: What do mean by loop through external array ? The above following is a string.

Comment: Before you made an edit, no one could've ever guessed that it's a string.

Comment: Kunal Shah, I am sorry about that.

Comment: This can be solved using a stack. Pop each '[' into a stack and keep pushing in elements till you reach an " (open quotes). The keep track of what comes after until you reach a " (close quotes). Ignore the elements, if you get an alphanumeric character without a preceeding open quote. Continue this until you reach the end of the string.

Comment: Can you add your sample code into the answer ? I kinda get what you mean but i have no idea how to write the code.