# Search to extract words inside single quotes or double quotes from a sentence. in javascript

Tags: javascript

Example :work "work & work

Result : ["work & work"]

Example : Exercise is "good" for "health"
Result : ["good", "health"]

I wanted them in javascript

Comment: [StackOverflow isn't here to do your work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Show us what you have tried so far. We'll gladly help you.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks) is what you're looking for, including the snippet below with explanation for quick reference.

```
(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1
```

As an example using Javascript:

```
function getWordsBetweenQuotes(str) {
    return str.match(/(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1/g);
}
```

> ([""']) match a quote; ((?=(\?))\2.) if backslash exists, gobble it, and whether or not that happens, match a character; *? match many times (non-greedily, as to not eat the closing quote); \1 match the same quote that was use for opening.

Comment: Strange, please provide the full sentence?

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```js
function getResult(str){
    return str.split('"').filter((e, i) => (i&1))
}

console.log(getResult('work "work & work'));
console.log(getResult('Exercise is "good" for "health"'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a regexp like this will work:

```
str.match(/\w+|"[^"]+"/g)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var words = 'Exercise is "good" for "health"'.match(/(?<=")([\w]*?)(?=")/g);

console.log(words)
```