# how to extract values inside quote using regex python 3.x

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have following

```
\"url\": \"\\\/maru.php?superalox=1\", \"params\": {\"params\": \"EgtmbUtXdUZWdDF2SSoCCABQAQ%3D%3D\", \"session_value\": \"QUFFLUhqbnQ4eW5HeEZYdDBULU5EVk1LREU2VndMMm1nd3xBQ3Jtc0trMUlMOWRqTWxpS0pOT2pNUVN6RENVU3k0Tmc4blplodexsWkxrVDRmOUN2Q0lXVkl1N0YwUFhoV1puQ3ZFQm10X1RzNWR4Q3RUeG5kMkdLNnNobTUyRkNuaG90d2c=\"}, \"log_params\":
```

i want to extract the value of params which is `EgtmbUtXdUZWdDF2SSoCCABQAQ%3D%3D`

i have tried this but it didnt work

```
my_text = """ \"url\": \"\\\/maru.php?superalox=1\", \"params\": {\"params\": \"EgtmbUtXdUZWdDF2SSoCCABQAQ%3D%3D\", \"session_value\": \"QUFFLUhqbnQ4eW5HeEZYdDBULU5EVk1LREU2VndMMm1nd3xBQ3Jtc0trMUlMOWRqTWxpS0pOT2pNUVN6RENVU3k0Tmc4blplodexsWkxrVDRmOUN2Q0lXVkl1N0YwUFhoV1puQ3ZFQm10X1RzNWR4Q3RUeG5kMkdLNnNobTUyRkNuaG90d2c=\"}, \"log_params\": """

extract_data = re.search(r'(\\\"params\": \\\")(\w*)', my_text)
print(extract_data)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
re.search(r'"params": "([^"]+)"', my_text).group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the following with great success:

```
(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1
```

It supports nested quotes as well.

This also works: (["'])(\?.)*?\1 Easier to read.

For those who want a deeper explanation of how this works, here's an explanation from user [ephemient](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20713/ephemient):

> `([""'])` match a quote; `((?=(\\?))\2.)` if backslash exists, gobble it, and whether or not that happens, match a character; `*?` match many times (non-greedily, as to not eat the closing quote); `\1` match the same quote that was use for opening.

This is copied from another answer found here: [RegEx: Grabbing values between quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks/171499#171499)