# How to capture this group with quotes in between?

Tags: java, regex

```
    String content = "$.test(\"I am do'in testing\") ";
    Matcher matcher = 
     Pattern.compile("\\$.test.*?(.*?[\"'](.*?)[\"'].*?)").matcher(content);
```

Output is  `("I am do'`  but i need to capture `I am do'in testing`. Not sure ehat i am missing here ?

Similarly input can be "$.test(\'I am do"in testing\')"  output should be `I am do'in testing`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx: Grabbing values between quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks)

Comment: @revo Its not duplicate as i need to escape intermediate `'` or `"`

Comment: Read other answers in that topic. There are a few to cover this.

Comment: @revo that's not mine requirement. Let me know if there is specific answer you want to point out ?

Comment: This one https://stackoverflow.com/a/29452781/1020526

Comment: @revo this one did not solve my issue

Comment: maybe [`^\$\.test\(\\(['"])(.*?)\\\1\)`](https://regex101.com/r/2dsbEP/1)

Comment: [Does this work for you?](https://regex101.com/r/KfrzdI/3)

Comment: @anubhava can you please let me know what's wrong in my regex ?

Comment: The problem with your regex is it does not account escaped quotes and it does not ensure the opening quote is the same as the closing quote. The latter explains the behavior you observed. The fourth bird's pattern solves this issue using a backreference:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\$.test.*?(.*?["'](.*?)["'].*?)
```

This is your regex. This regex is using lazy quantifier between `["']` and another `["']`. This makes it match between `"` (double quote) and `'` single quote when your input is: `$.test("I am do'in testing")`

Hence it matches and captures `I am do` in capture group #1.

Another problem is that you're not escaping dot after `$` which may result in matching any character instead of literal dot.

You may use this regex to match string between both single or double quotes that **skips escaped quotes** with a backslash:

```
\$\.test[^'"]*(?:"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|'((?:[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*))').*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KfrzdI/3/)

**Code:**

```
final String regex = "\\$\\.test[^'\"]*(?:\"([^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*)\"|'((?:[^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*))').*";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( input );

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.printf("Group-1: %s, Group-2: %s%n", matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
}
```