# RegEx : Capturing words within Quotation mark

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have a paragraph of text like this:

> John went out for a walk. He met Mrs. Edwards and said, 'Hello Mam how are you doing today?'. She replied 'I'm fine. How are you?'.

I would like to capture the words within the single quotes. 
I tried this regex

```
re.findall(r"(?<=([']\b))((?=(\\?))\2.)*?(?=\1))",string)
```

(from this question: [RegEx: Grabbing values between quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks))

It returned only single quotes as the output. I don't know what went wrong can someone help me?

Comment: Running your code gives me "cannot refer to open group" error. https://regex101.com/r/FNt7rO/1

Comment: Can you provide sample output (desired result)?

Comment: @Tim This regex *is* wrong. `\2` is referring to the capturing group itself is in.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's the error I get when I run OP's code in Python (which is separate from the unbalanced parentheses)

Comment: @iBug the sample output: Hello Mam how are you doing today? , I'm fine. How are you?. It should be displayed without the quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python requires capturing groups to be fully closed before any backreferences  (`\2`) to the group.

You can use [Positive Lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<=[\s,.])` and [Positive Lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=[\s,.])` zero-length assertions to match words inside single quotes, including words such as `I'm`, i.e.:

```
re.findall(r"(?<=[\s,.])'.*?'(?=[\s,.])", string)
```

---

```
Full match  56-92   'Hello Mam how are you doing today?'
Full match  106-130 'I'm fine. How are you?'
```

---

Explanation
[image]

---

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/J5ypw9/1)

Comment: Closing double quote is missing, I think.

Comment: @NickD, I've tested the code above and it works as expected.

Comment: >>> re.findall(r"(?<=[\s,.])'.*?'(?=[\s,.]), string)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    re.findall(r"(?<=[\s,.])'.*?'(?=[\s,.]), string)
                                                   ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal