# Get strings with regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have a command like this: `add "first item" and subtract "third course", disregard "the final power".`

How do I extract all the strings so it outputs an array: `["first item", "third course", "the final power"]`

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Use a regular expression that matches a double quotes, a sequence of non-double quote characters, and another double quote.

Comment: `str.split(/[\w\s,]+(\s|,)"|"./).filter(w => w && w.trim())`

Comment: Interesting and tricky question :) Please find the solution below which may be answer for your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx: Grabbing values between quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a regex that matches `quote`, `text`, `quote`, then remove the captured quotes using `map`:

```js
const string = 'add "first item" and subtract "third course", disregard "the final power".';

const quotes = string.match(/\"(.*?)\"/g).map(e => e.split("\"")[1]);

console.log(quotes);
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use a global regexp like this and just loop through

```
var extractValues = function(string) {
    var regex = /"([^"]+)"/g;
    var ret = [];
    for (var result = regex.exec(string);
            result != null;
            result = regex.exec(string)) {
        ret.push(result[1]);
    }
    return ret;
}
extractValues('add "first item" and subtract "third course", disregard "the final power".')
```

Note, however, that, most answers, including this one, does not deal with the fact that values may have a quote in them. So for example:

```
var str = 'This is "a \"quoted string\""';
```

If you have this in your dataset you will need to adapt some of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'add "first item" and subtract "third course", disregard "the final power".'; 
var res = str.match(/(?<=(['"])\b)(?:(?!\1|\\).|\\.)*(?=\1)/g);
console.log(res);
```

Reference : [Casimir et Hippolyte's solution on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks/29452781#29452781)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

***"[^"]+?"*** - Match `"` followed by anything expect `"` (one or more time lazy mode) followed by `"`

```js
let str = `add "first item" and subtract "third course", disregard "the final power"`

let op = str.match(/"[^"]+?"/g).map(e=>e.replace(/\"/g, ''))

console.log(op)
```