# A better way to extract some strings from a string

Tags: java, string

**Is there a better way to extract substring from a string ?**

I want to extract characters that are surrounded with " and " in a string. I used `substring()` and `indexOf()` methods but I sure there is a better way.

For example, for this input:

> I "learn" java "and" python.

The desired output would be:

> learn
>
> and

**Here is what I tried:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner putIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = putIn.nextLine();
    String subInput = input.substring(input.indexOf("\"") + 1);
    System.out.println(subInput);
    String strOne= subInput.substring(0, subInput.indexOf("\""));
    System.out.println(strOne);
    String strTwo = subInput.substring(strOne.length() + 4, subInput.length() - 2);
    System.out.println(strTwo);
}
```

Comment: You're not really doing any "extraction" here. What is your goal with this code?

Comment: Extract two substring that are surrounded with " and ".

Comment: Rather than repeating what you've already posted, please consider explaining the details. Your output is simply repeating the second String in your "method" call.

Comment: Input of the program is one string (that have to word that are surrounded with " and ") like: Dreams "keep" me "alive" this program must print two strings that : keep and alive.

Comment: Can quotation marks be escaped like `Tom:"What movie do you like?". Emmy:"I like \"Titanic\""`? What should be matched in this case? Are there any other cases which we should know about?

Comment: any string in the input that are in quotation marks like this: I like "learning" and "swimming". strOne must be learning and strTwo must be swimming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Pattern` and `Matcher` classes seem to fit your needs:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"([a-zA-Z]*)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Further explanation:

- `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"([a-zA-Z]*)\"");` -> Create a `Pattern` that matches letters between quote characters
- `Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);` -> Create a `Matcher` to link the `Pattern` and the user input.
- `while(matcher.find())` while there are matches... Of course you could add the matched strings to an array, here I just print them.

Answer (score 0):

I think regular expressions are perfect for your cause here. With the Pattern class, you can compile a regular expression and return the matches. Here are the details:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

For the specific regex you want for extracting between quotes, you can reference the discussion here:

[RegEx: Grabbing values between quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks)

The regex solution is nice, because you can easily generalize it beyond your current use case.