# Regex to match Method Signature

Tags: regex

I want to extract parameters values from a String that contains a method call. Example:

```
sort("KAMP_MR","BEZ ASC, lower(KAMPNR) ASC")
```

I need to extract the parameter values:

```
KAMP_MR
BEZ ASC, lower(KAMPNR) ASC
```

I have a regex that works to some point

```
"[0-9a-zA-Z.,_()" "]*"
```

But this will match "KAMP_MR","BEZ ASC, lower(KAMPNR) ASC" but how do I split this by ,?

Comment: Are you using a programming language?

Comment: Use `"([^"]+)"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But that would match _any_ double quoted literal in the entire source code.  The OP wants to only target method signatures.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you that helped

Comment: [Here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29452781/3832970)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Wiktors solution is good enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to define a regex that works also with empty strings:

```
("([^"]|"")*")
```