# replace comma enclosed within double quotes in a csv file using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, csv, replace

How could I replace comma inside double quote using nodejs or nodejs moudle like fs ?

```
input: 48,"LHT0019","TEST COUNT (HB,TW,DC,PL)"
output: 48,"LHT0019","TEST COUNT (HB TW DC PL)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
'48,"LHT0019","TEST COUNT (HB,TW,DC,PL)"' // Your string
  .replace(
    /(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1/g, // REGEX to find text in quotes
    function(match, capture) { // Pass result to a function to modify further
      return match.replace(/\,/g, ' '); // REGEX to remove all ","
    }
  );
```

Uses REGEX to find and then modify the strings.

With a little help from [RegEx: Grabbing values between quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks)

Answer (score 0):

You ca use `str.replace` as follows

```
var str  = "TEST COUNT (HB,TW,DC,PL)";
console.log("rrrr", str.replace(/,/g," "));
```

OUTPUT:

`TEST COUNT (HB TW DC PL)`

Comment: This will replace every comma in the string though which might lead to unintended consequences