# Regex for finding the text inside parentheses followed by @en : "example"@en

Tags: java, regex

I was using `"(.*?)"@en` but it does not detect an input with three dots : `"..."@en`

This is the guilty line:

`<http://dbpedia.org/resource/%C2%85> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "…"@en .`

Is there a way to make it detect all characters?

I am using Java's `Pattern` and `Matcher`.

Comment: It works, see https://regex101.com/r/brcMGL/1. However, you'd better use `"([^"]*)"@en`

Comment: It didn't work in the Java program. However, your regex pattern did work. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: It is already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/171492/3832970). :(