# RegEx to return string between 2 quotes "?

Tags: text, between, single-quotes

I need to extract text between two single quotes (")  into the field "my_description":

> description="Env: Application: Upgrade  App for SNOW from 1.0.0 to 2.0.0  on server  myserver.mydomain.com.  This is being done to support the upcoming upgrade to the Patch 3 release.
>
> All changes and post-implementation verification will be done.
> This has been tested successfully  in lower environments."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx: Grabbing values between quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean with the

> into the field "my_description"

part, but you can find the answer here

[RegEx: Grabbing values between quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks)