# How to extract text with quotations and without quotations?

Tags: python-3.x

For example if the text is 'SetVariable "a" "b" "c"' I need to extract both text with quotation ["a","b","c"] and SetVariable. I found the regex to extract text within quotation marks. I need help on how to extract the rest of text

Comment: python `re` package offers regex utility. Use something like the pattern in accepted answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to parse a command line. `shlex` module can do this for you.

```
import shlex
x = 'SetVariable "a" "b" "c"'
shlex.split(x)
```

Result:

```
['SetVariable', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple version:

```
x = 'SetVariable "a" "b" "c"'
s = x.split()
spl = [i for i in s]
print(spl)
```

Output:

```
['SetVariable', '"a"', '"b"', '"c"']
```

Using Comprehension:

```
spl = [i for i in x.split()]
print(spl)
```

Output:

```
['SetVariable', '"a"', '"b"', '"c"']
```