# How to get all values between quotation mark with quotation marks inside value in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, quotation-marks

I'm trying to get every value in quotes using regex, in some situations I get it and others I don't.

**My Regex: `/(?:-reason|-r) ?"(.+?)(?:"-|" -|"?$\B)/g`**

Below are some sentences I've been testing, line 1 and 2 match regex, but line 3 doesn't.

```
1 anything -reason "some reason" -anyArg "anything"
2 anything -reason "Hello World, you're the "best"" -anyArg "anything"
3 anything -r "anything "here" is wrong" anything
```

The last sentence of the image is not compatible with the regex, what do I do to make the regex match them all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx: Grabbing values between quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks)

Comment: Please don't use pictures of code and data. For one, readers cannot cut-and-paste in constructing answers.

Comment: @Nick I believe the "solution" you reference requires that internal quotes be escaped, e.g. `"abc\"def\"ghi"`. See [this](https://regex101.com/r/OgoUlQ/1) and [this](https://regex101.com/r/WmuOCs/1).

Comment: @Booboo that's correct - but I don't see that there are any internal quotes in OPs data, although it's hard to be 100% certain since they have not indicated their expected result from line 3.

Comment: @Nick Look at Sentence 3 above: **anything -r "anything "here" is wrong" anything** (presumably the match wanted is **"anything "here" is wrong"**). But then why is Sentence 2. not a problem, also?

Comment: You need to specify for each sentence what exactly the expected match should be.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
-r(?:eason)?\s*"(.+?)(?:"\s*-|[^"]*$)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/usSz7G/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -r                       '-r'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    eason                    'eason'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .+?                      any character except \n (1 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
```