# Regular expression to match strings for syntax highlighter

Tags: regex, string, ide, syntax-highlighting, code-editor

I'm looking for a regular expression that matches strings for a syntax highlighter used in a code editor. I've found

```
(")(?:(?!\1|\\).|\\.)*\1
```

from here [regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50320848/1264585) (I've changed the beginning since I only need double quotes, no single quotes)

The above regular expression correctly matches the following example having escaped double quotes and escaped backslashes

```
"this is \" just  a test\\"
```

Most code editors however also highlight open ended strings such as the following example

```
"this must \" match\\" this text must not be matched "this text must be matched as well
```

Is it possible to alter the above regular expression to also match the open ended string? Another possibility would be a second regular expression that just matches the open ended string such as

```
"[^"]*$ but match only if preceded by an even count of non-escaped quotes
```

Comment: Did you try using an alternation? `(")(?:(?!\1|\\).|\\.)*(?:\1|$)`  https://regex101.com/r/lUz06G/1 Or also allowing escaped double quotes at the end `(?<!\\)"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*(?:"|$)` https://regex101.com/r/U8igf2/1

Comment: "[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*$ seems to work even with escaped double quotes at the end. Please send it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an alternation to match either a backreference to group 1 or assert the end of the string with your current pattern.

```
(")(?:(?!\1|\\).|\\.)*(?:\1|$)
```

But as you are only capturing a single character `(")` you can omit the capture group and instead of the backreference `\1` just match `"`

Alternatively written pattern:

```
"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*(?:"|$)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kRANEJ/1).

---

If the match should not start with `\"` and a lookbehind is supported:

```
(?<!\\)"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*(?:"|$)
```

This pattern matches:

- `(?<!\\)` Negative lookbehind, assert not `\` directly to the left
- `"` Match the double quote
- `[^"\\]*` Optionally match any char except `"` or `\`
- `(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*` Optionally repeat matching `\` and any char followed by any char except `"` or `\`
- `(?:"|$)` Match either `"` or assert the end of the string.

Comment: I'll stick with "[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*(?:"|$), the pattern (?<!\\)"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*(?:"|$) does not work when the string starts with an escaped backslash (\\)