# RegEx: how do I grab terms within or not within quotes?

Tags: regex

I'm creating a search system, and want to support a mix of input terms, for example:

```
@bob "xxx",'yyy', "freak'd out" 'bob two' "" can I #handle/children #nope @ok(42)
```

I'd like a regex to grab all the insides of balanced quotes (not tripping over the

To make matters worse, I want to support common search operators that can be prefixed to words or quotes phrases, like so:

```
+@bob "xxx",'yyy', "freak'd out" -'bob two' "" can I #handle/children -#nope @ok(42)
```

and in the case of -'bob two' I want to land up with `-bob two`.
I also want to ignore the empty `""`.

Comment: Maybe something simple like [`[+-]?(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[@#]?[^"'#@+-]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/22ksym/1) would suffice but I doubt it :p You'd need to do further parsing with this one, is just to split into desired parts...

Answer (score 1):

I found [this answer to a simpler version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks?rq=1) and built on it, landing up with:

```
/\s([\-\+\!]?)([\-\+\!]?)(?:([\'"])(.+?)\3)|([\-\+\!]?[\w\-#@\/\(\)]+)/g
```

You can try it out here: https://regex101.com/r/8xxydh/1

This needs some post-processing in order to get out what I need, but it's simply concatenating match groups

- 1 (optional operator prefix)
- 4 (phrase inside quotes)
- 5 (word not in quotes)

(You won't get both 4 and 5 in a result.)

Doing this I get the following list:

1. +@bob
2. xxx
3. yyy
4. freak'd out
5. -bob two'
6. can
7. I
8. #handle/children
9. -#nope
10. @ok(42)