# Detect word between double qoute

Tags: regex

how to detect a word/phrase written between double quotes using regular expression . if the same word is written outside the double quotes it should not be considered.

Some test cases:

```
dim a as string = " test"  ( test should be detected)
dim a as string = "abc  test xyz"  ( test should be detected)
dim test as string = "abc"  ( test should not be detected)
dim str as string = "select id from " & test & "where place" (test should not be detected)
```

Below regex tested, but didn't worked :

```
"([^"]*test)"
"(.*test?)"
"(.*test.*?[^\\])"
\"([^\"]*?test[^\"]*?)\"
```

Is there any option to find text inside double quotes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks
Check this Answer It may

Answer (score 0):

An approach is to first design a regex that matches when the opposite is true, i.e. when there is no "test" between quotes:

```
^(?:\\.|[^"]|"(?:\\.|(?!test)[^"])*")*$
```

Explanation:

- `\\.` matches an escape pair. If this is not the case, then:
- `[^"]` matches any character that is not a double quote. If this is not the case, then:
- `"     "` matches a quoted substring, where:

  - `\\.` matches again an escape pair
  - `(?!test)[^"]` matches any other character that is not a double quote, but it cannot be a "t" either when that is the start of "test".
- These matching options are repeated with `*` and must continue to give a match until the end of the input string (`$`)

Now we can invert that regular expression, by making it a negative look-ahead that is made at the very start of the input. The `.*` at the end is optional. Without it, the match is a success, but with a zero length match. If you add it, then the whole input is matched. If your input is multiline, then use the `s` flag so `.` will also match newline characters:

```
^(?!(?:\\.|[^"]|"(?:\\.|(?!test)[^"])*")*$).*
```

View it on your test cases: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/PlqiFb/1)