# Regex expression with substring and single quotes

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to capture the same data from two strings where one may or may not be a substring of the other.

The data is being captured from two different sources.  Either could be like

```
NAME: ABC14DEF:1
```

or

```
NAME: 1 'ABC14DEF:1'
```

I want to capture

```
ABC14DEF:1
```

only as a group using re in python and do not want to capture

```
NAME:
```

or the leading

```
1 '
```

or the trailing

```
'
```

The same expression needs to capture the exact same string for either scenario.

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks) I tried

```
ABC:\s\w?\s?'?(([^']*))'?
```

which works for the second case, but misses the `A` in `ABC14DEF:1` and returns `BC14DEF:1`

Comment: Keep it simple: if those are the only two possible strings, then [`\w+:[\w\d']+:[\d']+`](https://regex101.com/r/2dpjjq/1) will work just fine: "some letters, colon, some letters, numbers, or quotes, colon, some numbers or quotes". No reason to get hyper specific unless your data is going to include different input that you don't want but would also be matched by that.

Comment: `\w?` matches the `A`, which is why it's not in the capture group. You could try using `\w??` to make it non-greedy.

Comment: Or you could use `(?:\w\s)?` to treat `1<space>` as a group that's optional, rather than making each of them optional by itself.

Comment: To clarify, I want to capture ABC14DEF:1 and do not want to capture the leading 1 ' and trailing '  The same expression needs to capture either case.

Comment: Are you only interested in lines that begin with the literal `"ABC:"` or lines that match `^[A-Z]{3}:` or what? Is `"1"` in `"ABC: 1"` a literal, a stand-in for a single digit or a stand-in for one or more digits? Please clarify by editing. Such is the problem of stating a question in terms of examples alone.

Comment: The ABC: is always the same.  I've updated it in the example to NAME: because it doesn't have to match the ABC in the captured text.  The 1 could be anything, but is probably only alphanumeric.  What's important is that it is between the NAME: and the single quote.  The captured text should always be alphanumeric and possibly have a colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
strings = ["NAME: ABC14DEF:1", "NAME: 1 'ABC14DEF:1'"]
pattern = r"\w:\s*(?:\d+\s*')?([^'\s]+)'?"
for string in strings:
    match = re.search(pattern, string)
    if match:
        print(match.group(1))
```

Revised Regex in pattern

Output:

```
ABC14DEF:1
ABC14DEF:1
```

Edit the  condition in regex as per the need.

Comment: How would you modify the expression to deal with  "NAME: N/A 'ABC14DEF:N/A'" as well?

Comment: pattern = r"\w:\s*(?:[\w/]+\s*')?([^']+)'?" matches "NAME: N/A 'ABC14DEF:N/A'"