# How to get particular part of string in java?

Tags: java, string

I want to get the particular part of String from a complete word.

For example:

I have the following String.

```
# STRING_VALUES #
```

and a sentence is as follows

```
<p># STRING_VALUE #<br /># CMESSAGE #<br /># CUSTOMERADDRESS #<br /><br /></p>
```

From the above, I want to get the string as follows:

```
STRING_VALUES
CMESSAGE
CUSTOMERADDRESS
```

How to do to get the above string? I am stuck with this.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you at least read [the javadoc of the class String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)?

Comment: Are they all surrounded by a pair of # symbols? What have you tried?

Comment: String functions are available in java. chk it.. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: "particular part of String"? Can you describe that particular part please? In that case, people will be able to help you easily.

Comment: particular part is without #. ie. STRING_VALUES

Answer (score 9):

Use `split`:

```
String ss ="# STRING_VALUES #";
String[] parts = ss.split("#");
System.out.println(parts[1].trim()); // STRING_VALUES
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/4cwbU)**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is working partially. it displays <br />. how to remove that.

Answer (score 3):

For your specific case following code will work:

```
String str = "# STRING_VALUES #";
String result = str.substring(2,str.length()-2);
```

**UPDATE:** (Following code will work for you modified input string)

```
String str = "<p># STRING_VALUE #<br /># CMESSAGE #<br /># CUSTOMERADDRESS #<br /><br /></p>";

String[] tokens = str.substring(3, str.length()-4).split("<br />");
// tokens will contain [0] = "# STRING_VALUE #"
//                     [1] = "# CMESSAGE #"
//                     [2] = "# CUSTOMERADDRESS #"
//                     [3] = ""

ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

for(String  token : tokens)
{
    if(token.length() != 0)
    {
        results.add(token.substring(2,str.length()-2));
    }
}

// results has required strings
for(String  result : results)
{
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: ok.but i have collection of strings of the same. what about that situation?

Comment: Does the updated answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with regular expressions. See the classes [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html). The regular expression to find the STRING_VALUE string in your example would be:

```
#\s(\w*)\s#
```

This would return a chain of word-characters (letters, numbers and underscores) after "#" and a whitespace and before a whitespace and "#". The chain of word characters would be returned as a sub-match you can extract separately.

Alternatively, you could use [String.indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) to search for the positions of delimeters in your string and [String.substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) to extract parts between the delimeter position you found.

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

They will tell you:

Here are some more examples of how strings can be used:

```
     System.out.println("abc");
     String cde = "cde";
     System.out.println("abc" + cde);
     String c = "abc".substring(2,3);
     String d = cde.substring(1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the `String[] split(String regex)` method of the String class as documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: forgot to hyperlink something in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

If your string  would be of this format i.e., space seperated you could use String.split()

```
String ss ="# STRING_VALUES #";
    System.out.println(ss.split("\\s")[1]);
```

the above code return STRING_VALUES as output

Comment: I wouldn't use regular expressions for such a simple task

Answer (score 0):

You could use substring:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int, int)

Or you could use regex:
[Need regexp to find substring between two tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489567/need-regexp-to-find-substring-between-two-tokens)