# Javascript - Global replace string between tags

Tags: javascript

Could someone please help me with the regexp javascript code to replace all `<br />` tags with a newline "\n" character found within `<pre>` divisions.. For example, a **string** passed to the function containing the following:

```
<pre class="exampleclass">1<br />2<br />3</pre>
```

Should be returned as (newlines not shown, though I hope you get the idea):

```
<pre class="exampleclass">1(newline)2(newline)3</pre>
```

Another example:

```
<div>foo<br />bar<pre>1<br />2</pre></div>
```

Returned as:

```
<div>foo<br />bar<pre>1(newline)2</pre></div>
```

Note that the class and division content is dynamic, along with other content in the string (other divs etc). On the other hand, the `<br />` tag does not change, so there's no need to cater for `<br>` or other variants.

NB - I'm working with strings, not HTML elements.. Just in case there is any confusion by the way I have presented the question.

Comment: Graham: In a comment below, you say something that **really needs to be in the question above**, specifically that there is other content being passed as part of the string *outside* the `pre` tags. So from your comment, it sounds as though you're saying another example string would be "<div>foo<br />bar<pre>1<br />2</pre></div>", with the expected result "<div>foo<br />bar<pre>1(newline)2</pre></div>". That completely changes the question.

Comment: Thanks T.J. Crowder - right you are.

Comment: By the way - if you are using javascript, you are likely in a browser. If you render the string in a container, you can use DOM to parse it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use

```
str.match(/<pre(?:.*?)>(?:.*?)<\/pre>/g);
```

And then for all matches

```
replaced = match.replace(/<br \/>/g, '\n');
str.replace(match, replaced);
```

So probably something like this:

```
var matches = str.match(/<pre(?:.*?)>(?:.*?)<\/pre>/g),
    len = matches.length,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    str = str.replace(matches[i], matches[i].replace(/<br \/>/g, '\n'));
}
```

EDIT: changed to match `<pre class="">` as well.

Comment: No sorry Spiny Norman. There are other div tags in the string

Comment: but within the <pre> tag you will see the \n as it is,  not the new line.

Comment: @user160820 This question is to resolve a compatibility issue with Joomla JCE Editor and RJ_InsertCode. Within <pre> tags, newline characters are converted to <br /> upon loading an article (luckily it works fine when saving content)

Comment: Ok, then you could first get all occurrences of <pre> tags using `/<pre>(.*?)<\/pre>/g`, replace the `<br />` s out of that and then replace the old `<pre>` tags with the new ones. There's probably a single regexp you could use for this whole operation, but this should do as well.

Comment: That sounds like a great approach Spiny. I'm only familiar with global or single string replacements - could you guide me as to how I could handle multiple occurrences?

Comment: One more consideration Spiny - `/<pre>(.*?)<\/pre>/g` will not cater for `<pre class="example"> .... </pre>`  etc

Comment: comments on previous posts are now looking weird. I'll remove mine

Comment: Just insert some more `(?:.*?)` :)

Comment: Hi Spiny - thanks for getting back to me so quickly. It doesn't look like `str.replace(matches[i], replaced);` is working as intended. I tried passing `<div>foo<br />bar<pre>1<br />2</pre></div>` and added some debug alerts - I can confirm the code correctly detects `<pre>` tags and strips `<br />` though doesn't join the rebuilt segments.

Answer (score 0):

HAD it been a document then

```
var allPre = document.getElementsByTagName('pre');
for (var i=0,n=allPre.length;i<n;i++) {
   allPre[i].innerHTML=allPre[i].innerHTML.replace(/<br \/>/gi,"\n");
}
```

since `<br />` could be `<BR />` in some innerHTML implementations

Have a look here too: [Replace patterns that are inside delimiters using a regular expression call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180793/replace-patterns-that-are-inside-delimiters-using-a-regular-expression-call)

Comment: Thankyou for your contribution mplungjan, though I need a solution that works with strings (not document HTML elements).

Comment: but within the <pre> tag you will see the \n as it is, not the new line.

Comment: Not correct user160820, I think you are confusing the pre with xmp

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DOM to do this and avoid trying to parse HTML with regex. However, this will leave you at the mercy of the browser's implementation of `innerHTML`. For example, IE will return tag names in upper case and will not necessarily close all tags.

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/KYRSU/

```
var preBrsToNewLine = (function() {
    function convert(node, insidePre) {
        if (insidePre && node.nodeType == 1 && node.nodeName == "BR") {
            node.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode("\n"), node);
        } else {
            insidePre = insidePre || (node.nodeType == 1 && node.nodeName == "PRE");
            for (var i = 0, children = node.childNodes, len = children.length; i < len; ++i) {
                convert(children[i], insidePre);
            }
        }
    }

    return function(str) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = str;
        convert(div, false);
        return div.innerHTML;
    }
})();

var str = "<div>foo<br />bar<pre>1<br />2</pre></div>";
window.alert(preBrsToNewLine(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

I (and others) think its a bad idea to use regular expressions to parse html (or xml). You probably want to use a recursive state machine. Will something like this resolve the issue? There's a lot of room to optimize, but I think it illustrates.

```
function replace(input, pre) {
    var output = [];
    var tag = null;
    var tag_re = /<(\w+)[^>]*?(\/)?>/; // This is a bit simplistic and will have problems with > in attribute values
    while (tag_re.exec(input)) {
        output.push(RegExp.leftContext);
        input = RegExp.rightContext;
        tag = RegExp.$1;
        if (pre && tag == 'br') {
            output.push('\n');
        } else {
            output.push(RegExp.lastMatch);
        }

        if (!RegExp.$2) {
            // not a self closing tag
            output.push(replace(input, tag=='pre'));
            return output.join('');
        }
    }
    output.push(input);
    return output.join('');
}
```