# Regex - Match string between quotes (") but do not match (\") before the string

Tags: regex

I need to match a string that is in quotations, but make sure the first quotation is not escaped.

For example: **First \"string\" is "Hello \"World\"!"** 

Should match only **Hello \"World\"!**

I am trying to modify `(")(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?"`

I tried adding `[^\\"]` to `(")`, and that kinda works, but it matches either only (") or every other letter that isn't (\") and I can't figure out a way to modify `([\\"]")` to only match (") if it is not (\")

This is what I have so far `([^\\"]")(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?"`

I've been trying to figure it out using these two pages, but still cannot get it.

[Can Regex be used for this particular string manipulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138552/can-regex-be-used-for-this-particular-string-manipulation)

[RegEx: Grabbing values between quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks)


Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative look behind like this:

```
(?<!\\)"(.*?)(?<!\\)"
```

Check see it in action [here on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/xN2sI8)

The first match group contains:

```
Hello \"World\"!
```

Comment: This expression, however, will not work if you have multiple _inline_ strings.

Comment: This won't work if there is a string like: `"ended by backslash\\"`. It needs to check if there's an odd number of backslashes preceding.

Comment: @Porges like tripple nested values or what? As far as I know it is not possible with regex to do that kind of (dynamic) matching!? - furthermore I would consider if I was using the right data structure :)